# Help needed Applications Fourier transform on sound wave propagatiom

Tags: applications

[This image show an example in a textbook that am having difficulty in understand how they get 2.12.81 and 2.12.82][1]

Kindly help with the value of B
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4HaF.jpg

Comment: Hi, I highly recommend you to take a [tour](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), in order to avoid downvotes. If the question is well written surely someone will come to help!